# tf.summary.image gets the error InvalidArgumentError

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I have train my data with cnn model and shuffle images. The first convolution layer is defined:

```
 with tf.name_scope("conv1") as scope:
    image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [FLAGS.batch_size, 32, 32, 1])
    image = tf.reshape(image, [FLAGS.batch_size, 32, 32, 1])
    print(image)

    w_conv1 = weight_variable([7, 7, 1, 50])
    tf.summary.histogram('w_conv1', w_conv1)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(image, w_conv1, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([50])
    tf.summary.histogram('b_conv1', b_conv1)
    conv1 = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, b_conv1)
    tf.summary.image('conv1_img',conv1)# **this line get the error**
    print('conv1:')
    print(conv1)
```

if I remove the line" tf.summary.image('conv1_img',conv1)", program can run successfully. When I add this line ,the error:

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a`v`alue for placeholder tensor 'conv1/Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [30,32,32,1]`

happens,why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summary of you define with `tf.summary.image` is automatically added to a collection of summaries.

You surely run the op `summaries = tf.summary.merge_all(key='summaries')` to collect all the summaries added to the collection named `summaries` (the default sumamry collection).

Then, once you run this op within a session with `sess.run(summaries)`, every summary previously defined is executed.

The histogram summaries depend on the model parameters values only, thus they don't need any external data to be computed.

Instead, the `tf.summary.image('conv1_img',conv1)` draws the output of the `conv1` op that needs a placeholder (`image`) to be computed.

Thus, you should execute the summary op feeding the graph with the image placeholder:

`sess.run(summaries, feed_dict{image: <your image here>})`.

A suggestion:

Let the placeholder be a placehoder. With the statement

```
image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [FLAGS.batch_size, 32, 32, 1])
image = tf.reshape(image, [FLAGS.batch_size, 32, 32, 1])
```

you're

1. defining `image` as a placeholder
2. overwriting the python `image`  variable to a tensorflow operation.

Thus, when you run use the `feed_dict` parameter to inject into the computational graph a value for the image placeholder, you're in reality, overriding a tensorflow op (and thus you have to feed an already reshaped value to make it work).

Thus, it's better to let the placeholder be a placeholder:

```
image_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [FLAGS.batch_size, 32, 32, 1])
image = tf.reshape(image_placeholder, [FLAGS.batch_size, 32, 32, 1])
```

and then use it to correctly feed the graph:

```
sess.run(<your ops>, feed_dict:{image_placeholder: <your image>})
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, it's really helpful. I have solved my problem by "sess.run(summaries, feed_dict{image: <your image here>})."